# jquery click simulation is firing but no event take place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my case is a bit different from all I have seen so far. The element is found the click event is fired but that is it. there is an event loading on the button but what is supposed to happen doesn't happen.

Here is my click code.

```
$(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass:first a").click();
```

I also tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass:first a").trigger('click');
});




$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass:first > a").click(function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
```

all of them are giving the same results.

To notice I have multiple .rowclass classes, within which I have .btn-mybottonclass and within each .btn-mybottonclass I have a hyperlink. I however want to click on the first .btn-mybottonclass hyperlink. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: `there is an event loading on the button`, which event? show your markup.

Comment: i believe it is because of this `:first` use `:nth-child(1)` instead

Comment: When you want to only click the first, you have to select only the first. You can e.g. use `.first()` fot that. `$(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass a").first().click();`

Comment: use comma (,) between two selectors

Comment: Where are you seeing two selectors? It's a selector-chain. It's one, not two. For me.

Comment: it is better to show your html mark up for better understand on the problem

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: @eisbehr `$(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass a").first().click()` is different from `$(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass:nth-child(1) a").click()`

Comment: @guradio correct, it's different. But this is how I understand the question. Am I wrong? I thought he only want to click the first `a` inside of a `.btn-mybottonclass` on the document existing.

Comment: @ShaunakD the even is on hover which triggers a tool tip

Comment: @eisbehr we can only guess but on the given code in OP the way you created the code is different. look here `.btn-mybottonclass:first` he wants first element with class `btn-mybottonclass` then  find child `anchor` on it

Comment: @guradio thanks but I have tried it.. it had the same out come

Comment: @eskoba can you add the html mark up so we can see where it gone wrong?

Comment: @guradio I have to edit it because for privacy issues, at moment I am bound not to do so..

Comment: I am doing the editing to upload the code

Comment: @eskoba then i cant help you any further i can only guess with out seeing any html mark up but the code ive given you can work with it you wanted first element of that class right? so change `.btn-mybottonclass:first` into `.btn-mybottonclass:nth-child(1)` it means first element with class name `btn-mybottonclass`

Comment: _"I have to edit it because for privacy issues, at moment I am bound not to do so"_ Use different  tag names, how can the issue be reproduced, resolved, without `html`?

Comment: @ guest271314 I am editing the code

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution for those who are interested:

```
$(".rowclass[maininfo_name='XX'] .btn-mybottonclass:first a")[0].click();
```